# Set the image in the center of a child div

Tags: html, css

My code is like this

```
<div id="main_1" style="background-color: #FFD993;
        color: darkbrown;
        border: 1px outset #A61C14;
        -moz-border-radius: 25px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 25px; width:100%;height:20%;text-align:center;margin-bottom:10px;">

        <div id="left_1" style="background-color: ;border: 1px;
         width:60%; height:90%;text-align: center; float:left;">


        </div>
        <div id="middle_1" style="background-color: ;border: 1px;
         width:20%; height:100%;text-align: center; float:left;">
        <img src="numb/equal.png" alt="Klematis" width="100%" height="50%">
        </div>
        <div id="right_1" style="background-color: ;border: 1px;
         width:20%; height:100%;text-align: center; float:right;" >

         <img src="numb/1.png"alt="Klematis" width="50px" height="60px">
        </div>

              </div>
```

I want the image 1.png to appear vertically in the middle of the div right_1.

Searched a lot but nothing was helpful. please help.

Comment: 1.png already at middle of right_1

Comment: 1.png is set in middle in right_1 div. Please clarify you question by putting your code in jsfiddle.

Comment: Please avoid using inline styles…. [Why use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `position:relative;` for the parent div and apply

```
position:absolute;
top:50%;
margin-top:-30px; // height of element/2
}
```

for the element to be vertically centered…

If ancient browser support is not an issue you can use css3 flex,

apply

```
display:flex;
align-items:center;
```

for the parent div.

Answer (score 1):

your code should be like this:

css:

```
   #right_1 {
   position:relative;
   }

   #right_1 img {
   position:absolute; 
   right:50%; 
   margin-right:-25px; 
   top:50%; 
   margin-top:-30px;
   }
```

---

and i think its better to use a size with pixel instead of % .
good luck